# capture livestream frames from Insta360 one RS camera

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I simply trying to display a "real time" frames from the insta360 one rs 1-inch camera.

I'm using it's on SDK to send my computer menage the camera.

However, I cant just open my camera from CaptureVideo(index) or something similar to this.

here is the base code that I'm using. (OPTION 10 on if-elses)

https://github.com/Insta360Develop/CameraSDK-Cpp/blob/master/demo/main.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <camera/camera.h>
#include <camera/photography_settings.h>
#include <camera/device_discovery.h>
#include <regex>

class TestStreamDelegate : public ins_camera::StreamDelegate {
public:
    TestStreamDelegate() {
        file1_ = fopen("./01.h264", "wb");
        file2_ = fopen("./02.h264", "wb");
    }
    ~TestStreamDelegate() {
        fclose(file1_);
        fclose(file2_);
    }

    void OnAudioData(const uint8_t* data, size_t size, int64_t timestamp) override {
        std::cout << "on audio data:" << std::endl;
    }
    void OnVideoData(const uint8_t* data, size_t size, int64_t timestamp, uint8_t streamType, int stream_index = 0) override {
        //std::cout << "on video frame:" << size << ";" << timestamp << std::endl;
        if (stream_index == 0) {
            fwrite(data, sizeof(uint8_t), size, file1_);
        }
        if (stream_index == 1) {
            fwrite(data, sizeof(uint8_t), size, file2_);
        }
    }
    void OnGyroData(const std::vector<ins_camera::GyroData>& data) override {
        //for (auto& gyro : data) {
        //  if (gyro.timestamp - last_timestamp > 2) {
        //      fprintf(file1_, "timestamp:%lld package_size = %d  offtimestamp = %lld gyro:[%f %f %f] accel:[%f %f %f]\n", gyro.timestamp, data.size(), gyro.timestamp - last_timestamp, gyro.gx, gyro.gy, gyro.gz, gyro.ax, gyro.ay, gyro.az);
        //  }
        //  last_timestamp = gyro.timestamp;
        //}
    }
    void OnExposureData(const ins_camera::ExposureData& data) override {
        //fprintf(file2_, "timestamp:%lld shutter_speed_s:%f\n", data.timestamp, data.exposure_time);
    }

private:
    FILE* file1_;
    FILE* file2_;
    int64_t last_timestamp = 0;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "begin open camera" << std::endl;
    ins_camera::DeviceDiscovery discovery;
    auto list = discovery.GetAvailableDevices();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        auto desc = list[i];
        std::cout << "serial:" << desc.serial_number << "\t"
            << "camera type:" << int(desc.camera_type) << "\t"
            << "lens type:" << int(desc.lens_type) << std::endl;
    }

    if (list.size() <= 0) {
        std::cerr << "no device found." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<ins_camera::Camera> cam = std::make_shared<ins_camera::Camera>(list[0].info);
    //ins_camera::Camera cam(list[0].info);
    if (!cam->Open()) {
        std::cerr << "failed to open camera" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "http base url:" << cam->GetHttpBaseUrl() << std::endl;

    std::shared_ptr<ins_camera::StreamDelegate> delegate = std::make_shared<TestStreamDelegate>();
    cam->SetStreamDelegate(delegate);

    discovery.FreeDeviceDescriptors(list);

    std::cout << "Succeed to open camera..." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Usage" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1: take photo" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2: get serial number" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3: get file list(only video and photo)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4: delete file" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "5: download file" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "6: start recording" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "7: stop recording" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "8: test set exposure settings:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "9: test set capture settings:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "10: start preview live streaming:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "11: stop preview live streaming:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "16: get uuid " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "17: test take photo and download " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "18: get current capture status " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "19: start timelapse " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "20: stop timelapse " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "21: get batty " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "22: get storage info " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "0: exit" << std::endl;

    auto camera_type = cam->GetCameraType();

    auto start = time(NULL);
    cam->SyncLocalTimeToCamera(start);

    int option;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "please enter index: ";
        std::cin >> option;
        if (option < 0 || option > 30) {
            std::cout << "Invalid index" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        if (option == 0) {
            break;
        }

        // take photo
        if (option == 1) {
            const auto url = cam->TakePhoto();
            if (!url.IsSingleOrigin() || url.Empty()) {
                std::cout << "failed to take picture" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            std::cout << "Take picture done: " << url.GetSingleOrigin() << std::endl;
        }

        // get serial number from camera
        if (option == 2) {
            const auto serial_number = cam->GetSerialNumber();
            if (serial_number.empty()) {
                std::cout << "failed to get serial number" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            std::cout << "serial number: " << serial_number << std::endl;
        }

        // get camera file list(only video and photo for now)
        if (option == 3) {
            const auto file_list = cam->GetCameraFilesList();
            for (const auto& file : file_list) {
                std::cout << "File: " << file << std::endl;
            }
        }

        // delete file from camera
        if (option == 4) {
            std::string file_to_delete;
            std::cout << "please input full file path to delete: ";
            std::cin >> file_to_delete;
            const auto ret = cam->DeleteCameraFile(file_to_delete);
            if (ret) {
                std::cout << "Deletion succeed" << std::endl;
            }
        }

        // download file from camera
        if (option == 5) {
            std::string file_to_download;
            std::string file_to_save;
            std::cout << "please input full file path to download: ";
            std::cin >> file_to_download;
            std::cout << "please input full file path to save: ";
            std::cin >> file_to_save;

            const auto ret = cam->DownloadCameraFile(file_to_download,
                file_to_save);
            if (ret) {
                std::cout << "Download " << file_to_download << " succeed!!!" << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Download " << file_to_download << " failed!!!" << std::endl;
            }
        }

        if (option == 6) {
            if (!cam->SetVideoCaptureParams({
                    ins_camera::VideoResolution::RES_3040_3040P24,
                    1024 * 1024 * 10
                }, ins_camera::CameraFunctionMode::FUNCTION_MODE_NORMAL_VIDEO)) {
                std::cerr << "failed to set capture settings." << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                auto ret = cam->StartRecording();
                if (ret) {
                    std::cerr << "success!" << std::endl;
                }
                else {
                    std::cerr << "failed to start recording" << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }

        if (option == 7) {
            auto url = cam->StopRecording();
            if (url.Empty()) {
                std::cerr << "stop recording failed" << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            auto& origins = url.OriginUrls();
            std::cout << "stop recording success" << std::endl;
            for (auto& origin_url : origins) {
                std::cout << "url:" << origin_url << std::endl;
            }
        }

        if (option == 8) {
            auto exposure_settings = cam->GetExposureSettings(ins_camera::CameraFunctionMode::FUNCTION_MODE_NORMAL_IMAGE);
            if (exposure_settings) {
                std::cout << "EVBias : " << exposure_settings->EVBias() << std::endl;
                std::cout << "ISO    : " << exposure_settings->Iso() << std::endl;
                std::cout << "speed  : " << exposure_settings->ShutterSpeed() << std::endl;
            }

            int bias;
            std::cout << "please enter EVBIOS: ";
            std::cin >> bias;
            auto exposure = std::make_shared<ins_camera::ExposureSettings>();
            auto exposure_mode = ins_camera::PhotographyOptions_ExposureMode::PhotographyOptions_ExposureOptions_Program_AUTO;
            if (camera_type == ins_camera::CameraType::Insta360X3) {
                exposure_mode = ins_camera::PhotographyOptions_ExposureMode::PhotographyOptions_ExposureOptions_Program_FULL_AUTO;
            }
            exposure->SetExposureMode(exposure_mode);
            exposure->SetEVBias(bias); // range -80 ~ 80, default 0, step 1
            exposure->SetIso(800);
            exposure->SetShutterSpeed(1.0 / 120.0);
            auto ret = cam->SetExposureSettings(ins_camera::CameraFunctionMode::FUNCTION_MODE_NORMAL_IMAGE, exposure);
            if (ret) {
                auto exposure_settings = cam->GetExposureSettings(ins_camera::CameraFunctionMode::FUNCTION_MODE_NORMAL_IMAGE);
                std::cout << "success! ISO " << exposure_settings->Iso() << ", WB = " << exposure_settings->ShutterSpeed() << ", ExposureMode = " << exposure_settings->ExposureMode() << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cerr << "failed to set exposure" << std::endl;
            }
        }

        if (option == 9) {
            auto settings = std::make_shared<ins_camera::CaptureSettings>();
            settings->SetValue(ins_camera::CaptureSettings::CaptureSettings_Saturation, 0);
            settings->SetWhiteBalance(ins_camera::PhotographyOptions_WhiteBalance_WB_4000K);
            settings->SetValue(ins_camera::CaptureSettings::CaptureSettings_Brightness, 100);
            auto ret = cam->SetCaptureSettings(ins_camera::CameraFunctionMode::FUNCTION_MODE_NORMAL_IMAGE, settings);
            if (ret) {
                auto capture_settings = cam->GetCaptureSettings(ins_camera::CameraFunctionMode::FUNCTION_MODE_NORMAL_IMAGE);
                std::cout << "success!" << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cerr << "failed to set capture settings" << std::endl;
            }
        }

        if (option == 10) {
            ins_camera::LiveStreamParam param;
            param.video_resolution = ins_camera::VideoResolution::RES_2560_1280P30;
            param.lrv_video_resulution = ins_camera::VideoResolution::RES_1152_768P30;
            param.video_bitrate = 1024 * 1024 / 2;
            param.enable_audio = false;
            param.using_lrv = true;
            if (cam->StartLiveStreaming(param)) {
                std::cout << "successfully started live stream" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        if (option == 11) {
            if (cam->StopLiveStreaming()) {
                std::cout << "success!" << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cerr << "failed to stop live." << std::endl;
            }
        }

        if (option == 16) {
            const auto str_uuid = cam->GetCameraUUID();
            if (str_uuid.empty()) {
                std::cerr << "failed to get uuid" << std::endl;
                return -1;
            }
            std::cout << "uuid : " << str_uuid << std::endl;
        }

        if (option == 17) {
            int test_cout = 100;
            int test = -1;
            while (test_cout-- != 0) {
                const auto url = cam->TakePhoto();
                if (!url.IsSingleOrigin() || url.Empty()) {
                    std::cout << "failed to take picture" << std::endl;
                    return -1;
                }

                std::string download_url = url.GetSingleOrigin();
                std::string save_path = "D:/testImage" + download_url;
                const auto ret = cam->DownloadCameraFile(download_url, save_path);
                if (ret) {
                    std::cout << "Download " << download_url << " succeed!!!" << std::endl;
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "Download " << download_url << " failed!!!" << std::endl;
                }
            }
            cam->Close();
            return 0;
        }

        if (option == 18) {
            auto ret = cam->GetCaptureCurrentStatus();
            if (ret == ins_camera::CaptureStatus::NOT_CAPTURE) {
                std::cout << "current statue : not capture" << std::endl;;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "current statue : capture" << std::endl;
            }
        }

        if (option == 19) {
            ins_camera::TimelapseParam param;
            //mode 是你相机所支持的模式
            param.mode = ins_camera::CameraTimelapseMode::MOBILE_TIMELAPSE_VIDEO;
            param.duration = -1;
            param.lapseTime = 3000;
            param.accelerate_fequency = 5;
            if (!cam->SetTimeLapseOption(param)) {
                std::cerr << "failed to set capture settings." << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                auto ret = cam->StartTimeLapse(param.mode);
                if (ret) {
                    std::cerr << "success!" << std::endl;
                }
                else {
                    std::cerr << "failed to start timelapse" << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }

        if (option == 20) {
            auto url = cam->StopTimeLapse(ins_camera::CameraTimelapseMode::MOBILE_TIMELAPSE_VIDEO);
            if (url.Empty()) {
                std::cerr << "stop timelapse failed" << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            auto& origins = url.OriginUrls();
            std::cout << "stop timelapse success" << std::endl;
            for (auto& origin_url : origins) {
                std::cout << "url:" << origin_url << std::endl;
            }
        }

        if (option == 21) {
            if (!cam->IsConnected()) {
                std::cout << "device is offline" << std::endl;
                break;
            }

            ins_camera::BatteryStatus status;
            bool ret = cam->GetBatteryStatus(status);
            if (!ret) {
                std::cerr << "GetBatteryStatus failed" << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            std::cout << "PowerType : " << status.power_type << std::endl;
            std::cout << "battery_level : " << status.battery_level << std::endl;
            std::cout << "battery_scale : " << status.battery_scale << std::endl;
        }

        if (option == 22) {
            ins_camera::StorageStatus status;
            bool ret = cam->GetStorageState(status);
            if (!ret) {
                std::cerr << "GetBatteryStatus failed" << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            std::cout << "free_space : " << status.free_space << std::endl;
            std::cout << "total_space : " << status.total_space << std::endl;
            std::cout << "state : " << status.state << std::endl;
        }

        if (option == 30) {
            const auto file_list = cam->GetCameraFilesList();
            for (const auto& file : file_list) {
                std::string save_path = "D:/testImage" + file;
                int ret = cam->DownloadCameraFile(file, save_path);
                if (ret) {
                    std::cout << "Download " << file << " succeed!!!" << std::endl;
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "Download " << file << " failed!!!" << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }

        if (option == 31) {
            const auto file_list = cam->GetCameraFilesList();
            for (const auto& file : file_list) {
                const auto ret = cam->DeleteCameraFile(file);
                if (ret) {
                    std::cout << file << " Deletion succeed" << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cam->Close();
    return 0;
}
```

With openCV I was able to read the file 01.h264 after it was created. But doing this write/read processes I get a hight latency...

In the function onVideoData I tried to capture the frames after it was writed by doing
CaptureVideo cap(*data) but it open the webcam

I just expect to get the strem spherical images from the camera...

Hope you could help me on this because I dont know what to do.

EDIT1: Debugging the onVideoData method, I notice that the pointer ‘data’ is pointing to null value but it is assigned to an memory address.
I’m sure that this pointer is doing something under the hood… but I dont know how capture this information.

How capture this data?

Comment: Could you also post this error stack?

Comment: @PavanDevarakonda there is no error occurring on the execution of the code 
I just want to capture and display the data. Like we did when we do cv::VideoCapture cap() using openCV

Comment: Did you tried any debug methods? or any print statements that gives where the flow is failing?

Comment: @PavanDevarakonda Yes, I debug and put a marker on method onVideoData. whatching the value of  the pointer data (*data) it keeps the value of 0. While the address of data (&data) never change.

Also, value of parameter size keeps change on each time.... this means at leat for me that is some thing being written on file1_

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve this using RTMP - start to stream your video feed to an RTMP instance - I achieved this by streaming the obtained data with ffmpeg library via RTMP ( flv container with the h264 stream + audio). Once done you can spawn a little RTMP server -  [Node Media Server](https://github.com/illuspas/Node-Media-Server) - and use opencv to read the RTMP feed (example here: [cv2 rtmp streaming example](https://gist.github.com/1f0/e3d9e830035d8bb4754a1777fca217a8) ). I tried to stream the RTMP feed from the camera to a local server - but it was difficult for my phone to target a local server. (i.e. camera connected to your phone via Wifi - i.e. the stream needs to go on phone data - unable to reach a local server)